# @StaticMethod or @ClassMethod decoration on magic methods

Tags: python, decorator, static-methods, magic-methods

I am trying to decorate the magic method `__getitem__` to be a classmethod on the class. Here is a sample of what I tried. I don't mind using either classmethod or staticmethod decoration, but I am not too sure how to do it. Here is what I tried:

```
import ConfigParser

class Settings(object):
   _env = None
   _config = None

   def __init__(self, env='dev'):
    _env = env
    # find the file
    filePath = "C:\\temp\\app.config"

    #load the file
    _config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    _config.read(filePath)

   @classmethod
   def __getitem__(cls, key): 
    return cls._config.get(cls._env, key)

   @classmethod
   def loadEnv(cls, env): 
    cls._env = env
```

However, when I try to call `Settings['database']` I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: expected Array[Type], got str
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong. Also, could someone suggest if there is better way to do this? I even tried using MetaClasses, but with little success (as I don't know python too well).

```
 class Meta(type):
  def __getitem__(*args):
   return type.__getitem__(*args)

 class Settings(object):
  __metaclass__ = Meta
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not pertinent to your question, but you're forgetting to assign to `self._env` and `self._config` in your `__init__` method. The class-level attributes `_env` and `_config` are also useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from Alex's (entirely correct) answer, it isn't clear what you actually want to do here. Right now you are trying to load the config when you instantiate the class. If you were to assign that _config to the class object, that would mean all instance of the class share the same config (and creating another instance would change all existing instances to point to the latest config.) Why are you trying to use the *class* to access this configuration, instead of a particular instance of the class? Even if you only ever have one configuration, it's much more convenient (and understandable!) to use an instance of the class. You can even store this instance in a module-global and call it 'Settings' if you like:

```
class _Settings(object):
    def __init__(self, fname):
        self._config = ...
    ...

Settings = _Settings('/path/to/config.ini')
```

Comment: This is the way to go: if you find yourself wanting to make a class behave like an instance, you're better off just using an instance in the first place.

Comment: You might be right. I am trying to make the Settings Globally accessible. Once you define the config environment, I want to load the settings (db, server, timeout) for that config.

Answer (score 6):

Python always looks up `__getitem__` and other magic methods on the class, not on the instance. So, for example, defining a `__getitem__` in a metaclass means that you can index **the class** (but you can't define it by delegating to a non-existent `__getitem__` in `type` -- just as you can never define anything by delegating to other non-existent methods, of course;-).

So, if you need to index a class such as `Settings`, your custom metaclass must indeed define `__getitem__`, but it must define it with explicit code that performs the action you desire -- the `return cls._config.get` you want.

**Edit**: let me give a simplified example...:

```
>>> class MyMeta(type):
...   def __getitem__(cls, k):
...     return cls._config.get(k)
... 
>>> class Settings(metaclass=MyMeta):
...   _config = dict(foo=23, bar=45)
... 
>>> print(Settings['foo'])
23
```

Of course, if that was all there was to it, it would be silly to architect this code as "indexing a class" -- a class had better have instances with states and methods, too, otherwise you should just code a module instead;-).  And why the "proper" access should be by indexing the whole class rather than a specific instance, etc, is far from clear.  But I'll pay you the compliment of assuming you have a good design reason for wanting to structure things this way, and just show you *how* to implement such a structure;-).

Comment: I hate it when I'm in the same timezone as you, grr :)

Comment: I tried changing the Meta class to 

class Meta(type):
 def __getitem__(cls, key):
  print 'Meta getitem on ', cls, ' key: ', key
  return cls._config.get(cls._env, key)
However, I still get 
Meta getitem on  <class '__main__.Settings'>  key:  database
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in __getitem__
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Any idea?

Comment: @Bobby, code's impossible to read in comments -- look at my example code, which works just fine, and discover whatever differences there are between my working code and your non-working one (or, if they just look identical to you, edit your question, **not** a comment, to add the code "allegedly identical to mine" that's not working and we'll see if we can spot the difference for you;-).

Comment: @Thomas, ;-) -- then you'd better convince Tim O'Reilly to move OSCON to the East Coast (since that's where I am now, at OSCON in Portland, OR... maybe we could try Portland, MN instead?-).

Comment: @Alex: nah, I just need to not visit stackoverflow when I'm in Mountain View :)

Comment: Thanks Alex, your example works. My MetaClass doesn't work due to the fact that the static _config (declared in my class) is set to None. It is initialized in the __init__ method of the Settings class. I think your explanation was helpful. I am starting to understand Python a bit more everyday.